# Environment Variables in Json file

Tags: json, configuration, environment-variables, config

Can system environment variables be used inside `json` file?

My `json` file looks as follows

```
{
      "db_host":"localhost",
      "db_user":"root",
      "db_pwd" :"password"
}
```

Currently I set all these values as environment variables.

Can I directly read the enironment variables inside json file, rather than directly hard-coding?

Comment: are you using nodejs?

Comment: I am not using node js. This json is a configuration file. Like in php file we can use 'getenv()' to get the environment variables. Is there something similar for json files.?

Comment: I don't think so. Let's see if some else knows about that.

Comment: I have same problem in nodejs. Can anyone tell me how to do this?