# Modifying Google Calendar API to accept environment variables rather than a JSON file for Heroku

Tags: python, json, django, heroku, environment-variables

I'm pushing a Django site (python 2.7) to Heroku, however I'm getting the error:

```
raise InvalidClientSecretsError('File not found: "%s"' % filename)
oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: File not found: "calendar_secret.json"
```

When running a cron job, and that's because my file calendar_secret.json isn't in my repo. I purposefully didn't push it so that the data isn't known for security reasons.

My question is about how to modify Google's default code found here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python, specifically the `get_credentials` method in order to use environment variables in either JSON or in the method directly so that I don't have to upload my calendar secrets.

Here's Google's code:

```
def get_credentials(self):
 """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

 If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
 the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

 Returns:
    Credentials, the obtained credential.
 """
 home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
 credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
 if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
    os.makedirs(credential_dir)
 credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir, 'json-file.json')

 store = Storage(credential_path)
 credentials = store.get()
 if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
     flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
     flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
     if flags:
         credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
     else:  # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
         credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
     print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
 return credentials
```

Which works great. But I'd love to either modify this method to use environment variables in JSON.

This is another take on the question: [Environment Variables in Json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672048/environment-variables-in-json-file), however the answer isn't something that makes sense here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! All you'll have to do is replace the flow code to the following:

```
flow = client.OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=YOUR-SAVED-ENV-ID-HERE,
                                  client_secret=YOUR-SAVED-ENV-SECRET-HERE,
                                  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                                  redirect_uris='YOUR-URIS-HERE')
```

More information here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth